# How fast would a race of humanoids establish a colony in Antarctica?

Tags: government, earth, construction, humanoid, supernatural

Say that there was a large supernatural portal that appeared in Antarctica and a large army of hive minded humanoids came out and began to colonize. These humanoids get all of their resources, up to and including modern tech, from the same portal that they come in and out of.

How soon would the governments of the world know that this is happening?

How long would it take them to establish a military city about the size of new york with modern construction equipment and full devotion of about 4 million people?

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: That being said, I'd say this is more story-based than opinion-based or broad. How soon the rest of the world knows about it depends on how you want the story to play out. If you want them to have more time, then they bring special technology with them through the magic portal that conceals them from the satellites looking at the southern pole. It's your story; tell it the way you want to.

Answer (score 5):

How soon somebody will know what happen depends on a lot of factors, some of them are:

- Where the portal open: near a human base or in a remote spot ?
- How the portal appear: quietly ? With an earthquake ? With some type of EM ?
- When it appear: in the summer ? In the Winter ?
- Have they some type of high tech camouflage to hide behind ?

So my estimate is that they have from days to months before someone will note something strange. After that it really depend on how strange is: probably a high concentration of some type of EM emission or radiation will trigger a patrol mission by some airforce (USA ? Brazil ?) in a couple of days.

Given that, I doubt they will be able to build something like New York without some sort of protection from our sensors, this include EM, radiation, optical: basically they should make the city appear out of nothing after they build it.

How many time it take depend a lot from at least two factor: how advanced they are (let's say they can build  an Empire state building in a month) and how many material they can pass througt the portal at any time.

Again, a good idea was at least a year assuming they have a lot of prefabricated components and the portal is basically like a road without limit if not the "traffic congestion".

On the other hand, if they have some really advanced technology (imagine a replicator) maybe they can be down to 4/6 months or whatever, here we are in a pure speculation.

Comment: Adding mass to the earth is going to change its moment of inertia. Enough mass to build New York is going to be noticeable by GPS satellites as a change in the rotational period

Comment: I add a mention of ice. At the pole there is an ice sheet measured in miles being under it would probably seriously delay detection. @bendl We add leap second fairly regularly without searching for alien cities. I'm skeptical the real New York is heavy enough to be a real factor and at the pole I think it would be even less important.

Comment: @bendl - I would assume that the portal and everything that is coming through it would be matching Earth's rotation speed. The extra mass would shift the axle, though, but the shift is going to be very tiny (orders of magnitude less than natural precession), and there would be no way to pinpoint the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

**- Detection would likely happen within days to weeks**

Many countries monitor the poles for other countries violating international agreements. The only thing that would delay this detection is if it was in a more central remote region and there was a storm occluding the ever vigilant view of satellites. Beyond this, you would need to camouflage development but more importantly hide IR because that is what satellites will be primarily looking for.

**- Beachhead development can arbitrarily take a month to years**

4 million people is a lot of people and a lot of people to support (food, waste, water, shelter). New York City is very large. Fortunately, for you the biggest factor here is organization(which is handled by a hive mind) and planning(which can be handled by science and the folks on the other side). With a hive mind you can coordinate actions and reactions to absurd precision. With technology you could modularize and specialize buildings and machines to the point they could be quickly transported and assembled. Assuming your race comes out of the portal in an efficient, non stop, organized, one way, conga line and immediately disperse to their function, I see no reason they couldn't  erect a city the size of NYC in roughly a month.

Answer (score 0):

> **They would be detected instantly.**

The U.S. National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) has weather satellites that blanket every square inch of the planet.  Even assuming the military doesn't (hah!), NOAA would discover the blemish (4 million people!) very quickly.  Remember, Antarctica is the litmus test for many global weather predictors (like global warming) because (a) it's cold and (b) it's untouched.

> **What's a "Military City?"**

If we're talking about the alien equivalent of [quonset huts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quonset_hut) with logistical organization for quartermastering and operations.  Then so long as it was planned out to the letter with practice beforehand, it could be done in a week or less.  No trees to remove, only basic "surface" flatening (I'm going out on a limb and suggesting if they can move all that stuff, they can pre-plan where to go to avoid sinking into the sea), and the ability to lay down the alien/arctic equivalent of [Marston Mats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marston_Mat) for road base.  It would be lightening fast.

The real limitation is the size of the portal, which you don't mention.  If it's one truck wide, my estimate jumps to 2-4 months.  If it's 16 or more trucks wide, a week.